# Custom Exception class shows Unreachable catch block everytime

Tags: java, exception

I've created a custom Exception class that I want to use in my application:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2151515147355511072L;
    private String message = null;

    public MyException() {
        super();
    }

    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
        this.message = message;
    }

    public MyException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

But when I try to use this class, like below, it gives a compile time error.

```
try {
    System.out.println("this");
} catch (MyException  e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Compile time error:

```
Unreachable catch block for MyException . This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
```

My question is if I'm extending Exception class & calling super in all constructors, then why this error is occurring?

Comment: You aren't doing anything in the `try` block that could ever throw `MyException`

Comment: Try to throw your exception in the block: `throw new MyException();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, you are not doing *anything* that'd generate a `MyException`. First write a method with the signature `throws MyException`, call it and then your problem is solved. Here is an example:

```
public void someMethod()throws MyException
{
    //some condition here.
    //if met..
    throw new MyException("cause");
}
```

and modify your main code as:

```
try {
    someMethod();
    System.out.println("this");
} catch (MyException  e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: U mean to say we need to use throws

Answer (score 4):

The exception you created is a checked exception and must be thrown from somewhere to catch it.
Any exception created by a java developer by extending `Exception` class is a checked exception. And the rules applicable for checked exception will be applied on such exceptions.

Another form of exception is called Unchecked Exception and usually created by extending `RuntimeException` Class. A developer is free to catch such exception without an explicit need for throwing it somewhere from your code.

> class Exception is also not thrown generally. I just want MyException behave like `Exception`.

This is what being further asked in one of the comments:

My take on this is you can think `Exception` class as a large container which have many different and unique(to the point) child exceptions defined. And mostly these fine grained exceptions are thrown from Java Code. In a abstraction hierarchy, Exception is at higher level (not Highest as, `Throwable` is sitting there).
Further, as a developer we all are always interested into the finer details like what kind of Exception is thrown. However, while handling exception, we sometimes write

```
try{
   //some code lets assume throws IOException
    //Some code lets assume throws FileNotFoundException
 }
 catch (Exception ex) {
  //common handling which doesn't care if its IOException or FileNotFoundException
 }
```

You can not intervene in this exception hierarchy by just writing `MyException extends Exception`. By this what you are doing is your `MyException` is a type of `Exception` not itself `Exception` class. So, you can't replace `Exception` caught in catch with your `MyException`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with:

```
try {
    System.out.println("this");
    throw new MyException();
} catch (MyException  e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Your exception wasn't thrown anywhere in the code. (try extending `RuntimeException` as another option)

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but exception of class `Exception` is also not thrown generally. I just want `MyException` behave like `Exception`

Comment: That is fine, and probably good practice, but then you really need to throw that exception somewhere in your code (where the exception might occur!). Calling a method that can throw that exception type (as suggested elsewhere) is a good way.

Answer (score 1):

What the compile time error says is right "This exception is never thrown from the try statement body". You don't have anything which throws `MyException`