# Custom Exception class to handle exceptions over entire application

Tags: android, exception

I've just started to write an application.

I want to create a custom `Exception` class that spans over my whole application.

Want to do this so that every exception can be passed to that class file & whenever a exception is occurred, the `Logs` can be stored in one place.

I tired using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22116175/3289817), but it does not seems an entirely good practice.

What is the best method to achieve this

*Thank You*

Answer (score 0):

You could try just making a general (non-Exception) class, and pass the exception to it. Something like this should work:

```
Public Class ExceptionHandler {
    public ExceptionHandler() {

    }

    public static handle(Exception e) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

in your code:

```
try {

}
catch(Exception e) {
    ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
}
```