# Eclipse. Why don't I see compile error if method with unreachable code doesn't invoke?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I noticed that if method with unreachable code doesn't invoke - then this code compiles by eclipse compiler and executes.

Demonstration:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class R3 {      
    public void g(){
        try {

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {//any checked exception

        }

    }
    public static void  main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("23");
        new R3().g();
    }
}
```

result:

```
Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
```

and compare it with following code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

class R3 {      
    public void g(){
        try {

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {//any checked exception

        }

    }
    public static void  main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("23");
        //new R3().g();
    }
}
```

compiles and executes normally.

Is it eclipse compiler optimization  or is it normal behaviour?

Comment: This code doesn't compile with a "real" Java compiler: "exception java.io.FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement" -- `g()` fails to compile

Comment: Why should unreachable code not compile? I know eclipse usually gives an error but as long as the code is valid (if pointless) I don't see why it's not just a warning normally.

Comment: Which means you have found yet another compiling bug in ECJ...

Comment: @fge Hence, eclipse compiler  is too tolerant for developer

Comment: @fge ECJ - Eclipse compiler ???

Comment: +1, apologies, question is deeper than I'd assumed.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse Compiler for Java -- some cynical folk would say "Excuse for a Compiler, Joe"

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `public/private` makes no difference when I try it (using `javac` directly).

Comment: Both of these examples will not compile with Eclipse compiler version org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.9.2.v20140114-1555. But Eclipse lets you run both examples, if you select to ignore the existing errors. Example 1 will throw a runtime error, and example 2 will work as expected... perhaps a fixed bug?

Comment: Neither of the codes compile on IntelliJ. Certainly an Eclipse bug.

Comment: @fge What is your definition of a "real" Java compiler?

Comment: @Balder one which conforms to the JLS

Comment: @fge And the Eclipse compiler does not conform to the JLS?

Comment: @Balder well, this question makes it obvious that it doesn't... It should not even give the option to ignore such an error, as the JLS doesn't give that option. And this is far from being the first time such a bug has been detected.

Comment: @fge Perhaps you are right... on the other hand, bugs come and go - also for the javac compiler. I think it is a little bit unfair to deny the Eclipse compiler JLS compatibility just because the user has the option to run code (in full awareness), that produces compile time errors. As far as I know the javac and jdt.core developer teams both do their best to stay as true to the JLS as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could contribute to the discussion.
When I compiled this with eclipse and THEN decompiled it online, this is what I got. For some reason Eclipse decides to compile your method to throw a runtime error that there was an unresolved compilation problem? Interesting.

```
class R3
{
  public void g()
  {
    throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problem: \n\tUnreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body\n");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("23");
  }
}
```

I found this somewhere else on SO, but it explains what happens pretty clearly.

> One notable difference is that the Eclipse compiler lets you run code that didn't actually properly compile. If the block of code with the error is never ran, your program will run fine. Otherwise it will throw an exception indicating that you tried to run code that doesn't compile.