# Why throws upcasting checked exception

Tags: java, exception, upcasting, checked-exceptions

I notice that methods in some sophisticated libraries, including the standard JDK, tend to `throws` upcasting exception. At first I found this phenomenon in the source code of Apache POI, later see it again in `java.io.FileWriter` like this:

```
public FileWriter(String fileName) throws IOException {
    super(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
}
```

where the instantiation of `FileOutputStream` declares the only checked exception `FileNotFoundException` in the this callstack. However, `IOException` is declared, which is the super class of `FileNotFoundException`.

So what is the reason for this? Or does it simply depend on the habit of programmer?

Comment: What do you mean by this? "However, IOException is thrown as its upcasting super class." That sentence is not at all clear to me.

Comment: What OP is asking is why `FileWriter` throws a more general exception than its only call to `FileOutputStream` would do.

Comment: @luk2302: I suspect that's the case, but it would certainly help if the OP could clarify. (There isn't any casting here... there's just the choice to declare a more general checked exception than would strictly be required by the code. The talk about casting makes this question confusing.)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610768/java-exception-handling-concept-why-do-compiler-allow-to-write-exceptions-in-th

Comment: Historical note: in jdk 1.1, `FileOutputStream(String)` was declared as throwing `IOException`. Therefore `FileWriter(String)`, which used that constructor, also had to be declared as throwing `IOException`. Subsequently, `FileOutputStream` (but not `FileWriter`) was changed to throw a more specific `FileNotFoundException`, but the Javadoc was then changed to read "throws FileNotFoundException if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason." It seems to me that this is a misleading exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may make sense to avoid changing the API too frequently.
Today, a method can throw in the code a subclass of `IOexception` but tomorrow it could throw another one.

While the parent exception declared in the signature is not too general and doesn't loose value for the clients, it seems ok to declare a base class for the exception.
For example, a bad use would be to declare `throw Exception` as the client could not understand the general meaning of the exception and handle it consequently.

Comment: Congrats. You are a lucky person today. I was just about to finish my answer when the question got closed out.

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry for that GhostCat, I still remember the first time when I posted here to ask something about java  and received your criticism :) (and that's what promotes me). Looking forward to meet you in more questions!

Comment: You are very welcome. And when no upvotes come in today, so at least some go out.